# How to import Sequelize in the dynamic import function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, postgresql, sequelize.js

I'm trying to import Sequelize in a dynamic import function:

[image: import]

Here is the content of the `database/index` file:

```
import { Sequelize } from 'sequelize';
const sequelize = new Sequelize('postgres://app_user:password@db:5432/app_db') // Example for postgres

export default sequelize;
```

I need to use a dynamic import function in order to load process env before initializing Sequelize instance (before import I'm calling a function that loads process.env variables).

But as a result, I received the following error from TypeScript:

[image: error]

What I'm doing wrong? How it could be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing async happening so the import does not need an await. You should just use the "normal" way of importing a default export:

`import sequelize from './database';`

Comment: I need to use a dynamic import cause I load module in the middle of main `index.ts` file